# Linear Regression with Constraints on the target in python

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have a classical linear regression problem (Y=Xw) that I would like to solve with an L2-regularizer model (e.g. Ridge). However, I have a constraint on the target Y > 0 (Y>1 in another case). Would you have any idea about how we can express this in python? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138550/strictly-positive-response-in-regression-what-should-my-default-model-be